# Good way to stress test my django on openshift

Tags: python, django, stress-testing

I am trying to find a good way to check how my django app reacts on getting many requests from many users. I impleneted this script using django's test client

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import logging
from django.conf import settings

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',
                   )
import os, sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app.settings'
script_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
project_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(script_path, '..'))

sys.path.insert(0, project_dir)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from django.test.client import Client
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment

    setup_test_environment()

    def stress_test(username, password, requests, wait):
        #create Client. Each Thread will have one
        client = Client()
        logging.debug('created client')

        #login user based on username and password provided
        client.login(username=username, password=password)
        logging.debug('User Logged in')

        #make a post request on /crm/customer/ causes django to execute search on customers.
        #needs ajax request
        #no of requests made by user
        for k in range(0, requests):
            logging.debug("Making search response with no args")
            response = client.post(reverse('customer'), {'doctor': client.session['_auth_user_id']},
                                   HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH="XMLHttpRequest",)

            #logging.debug("Wait..")
            sleep(wait)

        client.logout()

    thread_pool = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        if settings.DEBUG:
            thread = Thread(name="Thread-%d" %i, target=stress_test, args=('doctor1', 'doctor1', 10, 5,))
        else:
            thread = Thread(name="Thread-%d" %i, target=stress_test, args=('avlahop', 'avlahop', 10, 5,))

        thread_pool.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    for thread in thread_pool:
        thread.join()
```

Is this a good method to get some results? The post url performs search on my database. the view executed is the following

```
def index(request):
    search = False
    filtered = []
    customer_form = CustomerSearchForm(request.POST or None)
    practice_data = request.user.practice
    doctors = get_user_model().objects.filter(practice=practice_data, groups__name='doctors')
    customer_form.fields['doctor'].queryset = doctors
    customers = Customer.objects.filter(practice=practice_data)
    customers_no = customers.count()
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        if customer_form.is_valid():
            post_data = customer_form.cleaned_data
            empty = True if post_data.values().count("") == len(post_data.values()) - 2 and post_data.values().count(None) == 2 else False
            if empty:
                print empty
                start = time.time()
                search_result = customers
                end = time.time()
                duration = end - start                   
            else:
                search_terms = {}
                for field in post_data.keys():
                    if post_data[field] is not None and post_data[field] != "":
                        search_terms.update({field: post_data[field]})
                if post_data['doctor']:
                    customers = customers.filter(doctor=post_data['doctor'])
                    del post_data['doctor']
                    print 'doctor' in post_data


                search_result = []
                start = time.time()
                search_result = filter(lambda customer: my_filter(customer, search_terms), list(customers)
                try:
                    import operator
                except:
                    cmpkey = lambda x: (x.last_name, x.first_name)

                else:
                    cmpkey = operator.attrgetter('last_name', 'first_name')
                search_result.sort(key=cmpkey, reverse=False)
                end = time.time()
                duration = end - start
            return render_to_response('customer/ajax/search_results.html', dict(customers=search_result, duration=duration))

    search = True

    return { 'customers': customers, 'search': search, "customers_no": customers_no,
         'customer_form': customer_form}
```

and my_filter function

```
def my_filter(customer, search_terms):
    satisfies = True
    for field in search_terms.keys():
        if getattr(customer, field):
            if isinstance(search_terms[field], date) or isinstance(search_terms[field], get_user_model()):
                if getattr(customer, field) != search_terms[field]:
                    satisfies = False
                    break
            elif not getattr(customer, field).lower().startswith(search_terms[field].lower()):
                satisfies = False
                break
        else:
            satisfies = False
    return satisfies
```

I use for for models cause as I said in previous question customer model fields are encrypted . Is there any way I can optimize searching. Should I use numpy arrays instead of python lists? Can you tell if I hit my db too many times by my code? Is there a better way to check my django app in real world tests(many requests users etc)?

Comment: Just for the reference: there a tools built especially for (black box) performance testing. JMeter is one http://jmeter.apache.org/ - it supports scriptable user stories, so they can do more than just bang a simple URL.

Comment: I have seen jmeter just not sure how to set it up with django...

Comment: You set it up like with any web server. Django is not special in this sense. Just have a script which creates a database and then starts a Django web server against this database. Please note that you need to use a real web server in any case, Django's development server is not a performing one.

Comment: my application is on openshift running on apache. But authenticating in django uses seesions, I am not sure I have understood how jmeter works

Comment: E.g. create 1000 users beforehand with known passwords: user1, pass1. Then you can use JMeter to login these users by entering the credentials through the login form and then perform activities on the site. You can define ramp up period and how many paraller simulated users you want to cause the load. Then just increase the number of users until your sites starts breaking down (JMeter will report the ratio of success/failed page loads)